# Monitor a COM port already in use

Tags: c#, windows-xp, serial-port

Is it possible to read from a COM port already in use on Windows XP?

I would like to see the communication between some software and a device plugged into a serial device. I wrote a small program using C# to monitor the COM, but once it's in use by the other device it will not let you open it again. How can one monitor a COM port already in use?

I'm open to third-party software.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is technically possible.  You'll need a filter driver, a device driver type of a component that injects itself ahead of the native serial port driver.  It gets a crack at the driver IRPs before sending them on to the regular driver.

This is the technique used by SysInternals' PortMon utility.  However, you cannot write such a driver in C# code, the CLR cannot be loaded into ring 0.  At least not until the super-secret Midori project sees the light of day.

COM filter drivers are pretty common, check out [this one](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/index.html) for example.  You have to do some googling to find one that has a .NET wrapper though.

Answer (score 6):

[PortMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) is the classic COM port monitor. It has to be running before the program opens the COM port, but the monitoring part can be enabled/disabled.

Comment: Good remider to have PortMon running before the other program opens the COM port.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Portmon for Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) to monitor the activity.  The other way I do this is with some hardware and a laptop.  I'm not sure how you can monitor it yourself with a C# app.  Once you are connected to it and attempt to connect again it will already be in use.

Also check this out, it's somewhat related, with a note on how PortMon works:
[Serial Port Redirection or Splitting - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343033/serial-port-redirection-or-splitting)

If you have or can get more than one COM port, you could use a splitter and do the monitoring from the other port.

Answer (score 2):

[com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) may satisfy your needs. It worked for me.

Comment: I was going to suggest that as well